# Using @keyframes disabled other transform/transition animation

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

I had a transition/transform animation setup for the navigation title for my photo gallery web app. On hover, the colors would invert and it would grow in size with a transition attached. This worked fine:

```
.navbar-title {
    font-size: 140%;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    border: black solid 2px;
    width: 405px;
    margin: 25px;
    color: black;
    font-weight: 500;
    transition: transform 0.2s;
}

.navbar-title:hover {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

I then started playing around with @keyframes (not something I've used before) to have the other links in my navigation bar fade in when the page loads:

```
.nav-links a {
  margin-top: 25px;
  font-size: 21px;
  text-align: center;

 }

.oneSec {

  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
     -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox < 16 */
      -ms-animation: fadein 2s; /* Internet Explorer */
       -o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
          animation: fadein 2s;
}

 .twoSec {

  -webkit-animation: fadein 2.7s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
     -moz-animation: fadein 2.7s; /* Firefox < 16 */
      -ms-animation: fadein 2.7s; /* Internet Explorer */
       -o-animation: fadein 2.7s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
          animation: fadein 2.7s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

Now the original transition/transform animation I had setup for my nav bar title has been disabled and also some of the styling/formatting has gone such as the nav bar title border. Does anyone know why this is? The @keyframes animations work fine by the way. Also, I am using Chrome

```
<header>
<nav>
    <ul class="nav-links">
        <li><a routerLink="gallery-list" class="twoSec">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a routerLink="albums" class="oneSec">Albums</a></li>
        <li><a routerLink="gallery">BAILEY PHOTOGRAPHY</a></li>
        <li><a routerLink="favourites" class="oneSec">Favourites</a></li>
        <li><a routerLink="cart" class="twoSec">Cart</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Your code seems to be fine. Check out [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-wilbur-of205?file=/styles.css). Please try to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can have a look at your problem.

Comment: @Uchendu It was my mistake, I accidentally removed the class on one of the anchor tags. Thank you anyway though!